# Como pegar o valor de um campo JSON

Tags: java, json

Quero pegar as strings de dentro do campo `text` mas elas acabam retornando `null`.

O JSON que eu recebo é esse:

```
{"type":"RichMessage","message":{"type":"ChatWindowMenu","name":"Blitz","items":[{"text":"Login"},{"text":"Registro"}],"schedule":{"responseDelayMilliseconds":0.0},"agentId":"0Xx5Y000000g5uPSAQ"}}
```

Código:

```
JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(con.getInputStream());
JsonObject mresObj = reader.readObject();
JsonArray items = mresObj.getJsonArray("text");
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    JsonObject arrayItems = items.getJsonObject(i);
    System.out.println("items->"+arrayItems.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Você tá acessando o arquivo JSON como se ele tivesse uma outra estrutura. Veja o conteúdo do JSON de uma maneira mais estruturada e mais fácil de entender:

```
{
  "type": "RichMessage",
  "message": {
    "type": "ChatWindowMenu",
    "name": "Blitz",
    "items": [
      {
        "text": "Login"
      },
      {
        "text": "Registro"
      }
    ],
    "schedule": {
      "responseDelayMilliseconds": 0
    },
    "agentId": "0Xx5Y000000g5uPSAQ"
  }
}
```

No seu código, você vai precisar:

1. Pegar o objeto raiz do JSON
2. Pegar o campo "message" dele, que é um outro objeto
3. Pegar o campo "items" dele, que é um outro objeto
4. Iterar nesse campo "items" e pegar cada elemento-filho, que é um objeto
5. Pegar o campo "text" dele, que é um texto

Portanto, uma sugestão de código seria:

```
JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(con.getInputStream());
JsonObject mresObj = reader.readObject();
JsonObject message = mresObj.getJsonObject("message");
JsonArray items = message.getJsonArray("items");
for (JsonValue value : items) {
    JsonObject itemChild = value.asJsonObject();
    String text = itemChild.getString("text");
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Eu sugiro usar bibliotecas de leitura de JSON mais simples, como por exemplo [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).